# Setup a cronjob for PHP script in ubuntu & PHP

Tags: php, cron

I want to setup a cronjob for PHP script in ubuntu

I enter this command in terminal

```
$ crontab -e
```

Then I choose nano editor which is recommended by ubuntu. Then I enter the blow line into that. Then I press control+C, it asking Y/N for save. I press Y and F2 for close.

```
* */2 * * * root php /var/www/html/script.php
```

Other things I've tried:

```
* */2 * * * /var/www/html/script.php
* */2 * * * root /var/www/html/script.php
```

After that, I restart cron using the below command.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart
```

Then I check crontab list using `crontab -l`, it says no cron job set for the root user.

I tried to directly create a crontab.txt file into the cron.hourly / cron.d directory with one of the above line.

I tried numerous forum and all says `crontab -e` then enter or create crontab file inside cron directory. Nothing is helping me. I am scratching my head.

What is the correct way to create cronjob for php script in ubuntu 16.04 & php version 7.0

Comment: Do you have a new line character at the end of your cronjob entry??

Comment: no i dont have.

Comment: Add a newline character at the end of your cronjob entry and retry? :)

Comment: The first thing that you need to do is figure out what command you need to be running in the cron entry.  You're showing three different things right now.  Have you actually tried them directly on the command line to see which one (if any) works?

Comment: Do/did you get a `crontab: installing new crontab` after saving/exiting your `crontab -e`? Are you logged in as root or using a "regular" user?

Comment: yes i m login as a regular user

Comment: Do you really want to run the task at 60 second intervals in alternate hours?

Comment: @oldskool

if i will run only this command what happen - 
* 3 * * * root /var/www/html/script.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this to set crontab using root user,

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Do your changes via *nano* or *vim*. Finally save and quit

```
* */2 * * * /var/www/html/script.php
* */2 * * * root /var/www/html/script.php
```

**No need** to restart again using this `sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart`

Comment: i want to set crone job to run at 3 am.

Comment: which timezone ?

Comment: set it like `* 3 * * * root /var/www/html/script.php`, see also https://crontab-generator.org/

Comment: if i run only this command can set the cron job -

* 3 * * * root /var/www/html/script.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this one (as root user):
1. `sudo crontab -e`

```
* */2 * * * php -f /var/www/html/script.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

OR

```
* */2 * * * cd /var/www/html/; php -f script.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

for crontabs runing as www-data user use command `sudo crontab -u www-data -e` for editing

after save crontasks will be installed automaticaly.

OR
You can create **tmp_crontask_file** with content `* */2 * * * php -f /var/www/html/script.php > /dev/null 2>&1` AND next use `sudo crontab tmp_crontask_file` for install cron(s) from file (as root) `sudo crontab -u www-data tmp_crontask_file` (as www-data user).

---

Edit 1:
**WARNING!
If you install cron from file (last option) content of file overwrite existing crontab.**